# I tried writing a neural network in c++ (Just 2 hidden layers) and I am receiving an error which i cannot figure out

Tags: c++, eclipse, neural-network

This is the error I receive when I debug the code in eclipse.

*Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/malloc/malloc.c"
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.*

I read a similar question but that answer didn't work for me.
I thought it had something to do with memory allocation but I needed someone to confirm this. I am storing the values using (data structures) *vectors* and *vectors (vectors) * for (mathematical definitions) vectors and matrices respectively. Thank you!

Edit:

Line of code after which it shows the error :
`w2_transpose = transpose_matrix(w2);`
The above line of code is in a *for* loop(along with other lines of code). I have used the same function to obtain w3_transpose and didn't face any issues.

Other information related to this line of code:

````
typedef vector<vector<float>> Matrixx
Matrixx initialize_matrix(int row_size, int col_size)
{

    float rand_val = 0, extra_val, final_val;
    Matrixx result;
    srand(time(NULL)); //picks random time
    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++)
    {
        // construct a vector of floats with the given default value
        Row row;
        for (int j = 0; j < col_size; j++) 
        {
            extra_val = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
            final_val = rand_val + extra_val;
            row.push_back(final_val);
        }

        // push back above one-dimensional vector
        result.push_back(row);
    }
    return result;
}
Matrixx transpose_matrix(Matrixx& matrix)
{
    int row_size = matrix.size();
    Matrixx tpose(matrix[0].size(),vector<float>());
    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
        {
            tpose[j].push_back(matrix[i][j]);
            cout << "i value " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return tpose;
}```
````

Comment: We need more information. Q: What is the EXACT ERROR MESSAGE?   Please [Edit] your post.  Please copy/paste the error message, and copy/paste the line in the code that's giving the error.

Comment: `glibc-2.31/malloc/malloc.c` is a file that you _rarely_ should build as a part of your project - unless your project is glibc. How did that get added to your project?

Comment: @paulsm4 I have added some more information. I am unable to add images cause I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have not added any file in particular. I ran this in eclipse and in the debug phase, it took me to this error once I debugged the line mentioned above.

Comment: Oh, I see. Perhaps it needs the development debug package. Does it work if you dont compile it in debug mode? What is the exact (full) commandline that is used by eclipse to compile the program?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It compiles and terminates but I don't get the output.

Comment: @xos Got it! Then, the reason you get the error in debug mode is probably because it tries to show you where something goes awry. What package manager do you use? `dnf`, `apt`, `homebrew` or something else?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use apt I think. I am very new to all this. I just code and run the project but this is the first time I am encountering these terms. Sorry for the bother. Could it be that this "error" isn't really the issue and there's an issue with the logic of the code?

Comment: @xos If you are on Ubuntu, check [Debug Symbol Packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) - It could be that you are missing those. Another option is to compile the program manually, `g++ -o prog prog.cpp -g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then run the program. It may be able to pinpoint the exact line of your code that makes the program crash.

Comment: **==31621==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x604000759878 at pc 0x5610a38525e5 bp 0x7ffc6b803f90 sp 0x7ffc6b803f80**    I compiled it using the command. Then ran the object code it generated and this is the error I received. There are more details but stackoverflow does not allow that many characters

Comment: @xos Yeah, that's important information that you can get from compiling with those flags. It probably contains the line number in your code where you overflow the buffer too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yea thank you for that. I'll look into it.

Comment: @xos You're welcome. I'd still try to install the debug packages to be able to run the program in debug mode properly. It'll make everything easier in the future - but for a quick fix, using the AddressSanitizer is great.